# Declaring document-wide font size outside of the document class command

Tags: conditionals, fontsize

I have a document, where I want two versions: one versions 10pt size and another version, 2 page to a side 12pt. So I currently have:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,openany,article]{memoir} 
\newif\ifprintver
%\printvertrue

\ifprintver
\usepackage{pgfpages}  
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=1mm,landscape]
\fi
```

But I have to change the font size by hand. What can I put inside my `\if` that would change the font size document wide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your `printver` boolean before `\documentclass` and then use `\documentclass` inside an `\ifprintver` conditional:

```
\newif\ifprintver
%\printvertrue

\ifprintver
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany,article]{memoir} 
\else
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,openany,article]{memoir} 
\fi

% ... other code

\ifprintver
\usepackage{pgfpages}  
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=1mm,landscape]
\fi

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-100]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but you should swap `10pt` and `12pt` in your code example.

Comment: @lockstep: thanks for noticing, I've made the change.

Comment: I'm beginning to learn that "the first line in your `.tex` file must be a document class" is a LIE!!!! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

The KOMA-Script-classes feature the macro `\changefontsizes` which allows you to change the main font size mid-document. This macro is also part of the scrextend package, which can (or at least it seems so) be made compatible with the memoir class.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,openany,article]{memoir} 

\makeatletter
\let\@textsubscript\relax
\let\setfootnoterule\relax
\let\multiplefootnotemarker\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage{scrextend}

\newif\ifprintver
\printvertrue

\ifprintver
\usepackage{pgfpages}  
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=1mm,landscape]
\changefontsizes{12}
\fi

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should be noted, that the correct way to do this is `\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}`. changefontsizes is for calculating relative sizes like footnotesize for non-standard base sizes. Meaning the calculated values overwrite the default/standard values. But changing the fontsize means recalculating the type block. `memoir` has its own commands to deal with that.

Answer (score 3):

use a variable for the font size setting, e.g.

```
\documentclass[\FontSize, a4paper]{article}
```

and then run `pdflatex` with

```
pdflatex '\def\FontSize{12pt}\input{<your_file>.tex}'
```

now you can simply change the fontsize

Comment: You could also use `pdflatex '\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}\input{<your file>.tex}'`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a good idea, just to set the font-size. There are more subtle differences, such as setting equation number sizing etc. What LaTeX does when processing the options is that it imports a file with the sizing and other related definitions with the extension `.clo`. You can try this:

```
\input{size12.clo}
```

For each class LaTeX uses slightly different conventions, for example in the book class, it uses
`bk10.clo`.

Comment: The `.clo` files use `\newcommand`, so you have to undefine all of the sizing commands before this works.